# How can I import symbols from Flash CS in MXML?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-cs5, flashdevelop

I'm writing a mobile app in Flex with FlashDevelop and using Flash CS6 to create the visual assets. I created a symbol in Flash CS6 and exported it as AC3 into an SWC, which I imported into my FlashDevelop project. I then created a class for it, like so:

```
package com 
{
import flash.display.Sprite;

  public class volmeter_class extends Sprite
  {
    private var design:volmeter;

    public function volmeter_class()
    {
        trace("I'm a MySymbol instance called", name);
        design = new volmeter();
        addChild(design);
    }     
  }  
}
```

I'm now seeking to display the symbol I created on a page of my app. To do this, I suspect I am expected to somehow import it in my MXML, but I have no idea how to do so. Can someone give me a few tips on how to get started doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Flash Pro, assure AS Linkage is specified for the symbol.

[image: Flash symbol]

Using the published SWC from Flash Pro in the ActionScript Build Path of a project, the symbol may be instantiated by AS Linkage.  Or, symbols may be embedded from the published SWF of Flash Pro.

Pure ActionScript example:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class AppExample extends Sprite
    {
        public function AppExample()
        {
            var exampleSymbol:ExampleSymbol = new ExampleSymbol();
            addChild(exampleSymbol);
        }
    }
}
```

Flex MXML example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                var exampleSymbol:ExampleSymbol = new ExampleSymbol();
                symbol.addChild(exampleSymbol);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:SpriteVisualElement id="symbol" />

</s:Application>
```

Another approach would be to embed the symbol by linking a SWF from Flash Pro.

Flex MXML embed example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Embed('assets/library.swf', symbol = 'ExampleSymbol')]
            [Bindable]
            public static var ExampleSymbolClass:Class;
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Image source="{ExampleSymbolClass}" />

</s:Application>
```